# How to have git setup tracking branch on pull

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, pull

There are times when I'm pulling new changes from a repo that someone else changed. They have created new branches and pushed them to the central repo. Is there a way, when pulling these new branches, to get git to automatically create tracking branches of the same name locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think git supports this out of the box.

In case if this is only for one branch, you could do:

```
git fetch origin branch_name && git checkout -b branch_name --track origin/branch_name
```

You could also create a git alias for the above, by adding the following to your `~/.gitconfig` file:

```
[alias]
    fetch_tracking = "!f() { git fetch origin $1 && git checkout -b $1 --track origin/$1; }; f"
```

and then call it using

```
git fetch_tracking branch_name
```

Of course, you would do the above the first time only.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's usually not a single branch. I was hoping there was a way to do it automatically like it's done for the default remote tracking branch. I'll just do it manually then.